# rake how to fix undefined local variable or method error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, compiler-errors, rake, rake-task

i have a rake task as follows-

```
 desc 'send fetch request'
  task send_fetch_request: :environment do
  　　FacebookCrawl.new.process
  end
```

Yesterday this task working, but I don't know why it is not working today.
I am trying to execute this with the below command-

```
rake send_fetch_request
```

**Class details:**

```
  class FacebookCrawl

    def initialize                   
        fb_config = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join("config/facebook_catalog.yml"))
        @access_token = fb_config["facebook"]["access_token"]
        @product_feed_ids = fb_config["facebook"]["product_feed_ids"]
    end

    def process
        @product_feed_ids.each do |key,value|
            feed_id  = value["id"]
            feed_url = value["feed_url"]
            make_request(feed_id,feed_url,@access_token)
        end
    end 
end
```

I am getting below error:

```
rake send_fetch_request --trace
    ** Invoke send_fetch_request (first_time)
    ** Invoke environment (first_time)
    ** Execute environment
    ** Execute send_fetch_request
    rake aborted!
    NameError: undefined local variable or method `　　FacebookCrawl' for main:Object
    /Users/raj.sharma/Documents/Developer/Feed/lib/tasks/facebook_fetch_request_task.rake:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
    /Users/raj.sharma/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `call'
    /Users/raj.sharma/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `block in execute'
    /Users/raj.sharma/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `each'
    /Users/raj.sharma/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `execute'
    /Users/raj.sharma/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
    /Users/raj.sharma/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    /Users/raj.sharma/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    /Users/raj.sharma/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke'
    /Users/raj.sharma/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in `invoke_task'
    /Users/raj.sharma/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
    /Users/raj.sharma/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
    /Users/raj.sharma/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
    /Users/raj.sharma/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
    /Users/raj.sharma/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
    /Users/raj.sharma/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `block in run'
    /Users/raj.sharma/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
    /Users/raj.sharma/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
    /Users/raj.sharma/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/raj.sharma/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/rake:22:in `load'
    /Users/raj.sharma/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/rake:22:in `<main>'
    Tasks: TOP => send_fetch_request
```

Yesterday it was working fine, I don't why rake is complaining today. Please help.

Comment: Obviously, FacebookCrawl is unknown. Did you `require` the file which contains the class definition?

Comment: no,, Do I need to need to use require that class in rake? If yes how? I am new to rails. But it was working fine yesterday.

Comment: What is the location of FacebookCrawl ?

Comment: app/models/facebook_crawl.rb

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma I updated.

Answer (score 4):

Please, look carefully at the error message:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `　　FacebookCrawl' for main:Object
#                    ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑  ↑↑↑
```

The first giveaway is that you get a `NameError` for an undefined **local variable or method**, and not for a constant. The second giveaway is the name that Ruby complains about: it doesn't complain about `FacebookCrawl`, it complains about 　　`FacebookCrawl`.

In Ruby, only the Unicode characters **U+0020 SPACE** and **U+0009 CHARACTER TABULATION** are treated as whitespace. You have two Chinese **U+3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE** characters, which Ruby simply treats as part of the name, and since they are not uppercase characters, it treats the name as a local variable or message send.

You should probably turn on visible whitespace in your editor, e.g. this is how your code looks in my editor, making it immediately obvious where the problem is:[image: text editor with visible spaces showing the offending characters in different highlighting]

Comment: Thanks. It worked after removing those white spaces. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you know how to make white spaces visible in Atom editor?

Comment: Well, you see it in that it is **not** represented as white space. You can see it for instance in the screenshot Jörg used for his excellent analysis: The line containing FacebookCrawl contains 6 grey dots, representing white space, and then no more dots until the "F" of Facebook, so from this you can see that there is something in between which is not a white space in the sense of Ruby. I don't use Atom right now, but I would be surprised if Atom wouldn't display in a significantly different way.

Answer (score -1):

Copy the `facebook_crawl.rb` in `app/services` folder & restart the server.
This is your business logic, so it should be in services folder & not in the models
So create a services folder as well in the app directory.

Comment: After doing that do I need to include it in rake task? If yes how?

Comment: No, just copy the file in the services folder & execute your rake task

Comment: I moved it to app/services/facebook_crawl.rb and restarted server. Still same error.

Comment: What is your ruby & rails version

Comment: ruby --version
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-darwin15]
rails --version
Rails 5.0.1

Comment: @RajSharma: Try to remove the space from FacebookCrawl.new.process as told by Jorg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136436/discussion-between-chakreshwar-sharma-and-rajsharma).