# Remove whitespace from a string and then convert to integer

Tags: ruby

I am building a Rails 5 app.
In this app I need to turn a String into an Integer.

The string can look like this:

```
11 454
```

or

```
8 080
```

When I try the code below I can remove the white space and then .to_i

```
"8 008".gsub(/\s+/, "")
 => "8008"
```

But when I try another number it does not remove the white space

```
"11 301".gsub(/\s+/, "")
 => "11 301"
```

I need to first remove the whitespace before converting to an Integer otherwise I will only get the first digit for example 8 or 11.

What am I doing wrong?

**Updated**

Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn´t

```
2.4.2 :103 > "11 301".gsub(/\s+/, "")
 => "11301" 
2.4.2 :104 > "11 301".codepoints
 => [49, 49, 160, 51, 48, 49] 
2.4.2 :105 > "11 301".gsub(/\s+/, "")
 => "11 301" 
2.4.2 :106 >
```

**Updated 2**

Turns out it was a none breaking space and it was solved with (as suggested in the selected answer below):

```
value.gsub("\u00A0", "")
```

Comment: It works on my computer: `"11 301".gsub(/\s+/, "")
#=> "11301"` Are you sure it's the regular whitespace between `11` and `301` on your computer?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. What is `"11 301".codepoints`?

Comment: Codepoints is: [
56,
160,
48,
48,
56
]

Comment: @mrzasa How can I check the type?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Sometimes it works and sometimes it does not! Very strange

Comment: You should not have a Rails tag as this is a pure-Ruby question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html) says, `/\s/` is equivalent to the character class `/[ \t\r\n\f\v]/`. In other words, `/\s/` is a space, a tab, carriage return, a newline, a form feed, or a vertical tab.

You, however, have a [U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=00A0) character, which is not in the list of the characters matching `/\s/`.

A better alternative would be to match against a Unicode Character Property such as `/\p{Blank}/` or `/\p{Space}/`.

Comment: For reference: `[ 56, 160, 48, 48, 56 ].map(&:chr) == ["8", "\xA0", "0", "0", "8"]`

Comment: This is still the same outcome unfortunately (a String): value.gsub('/\p{Blank}/',''). Tried space too.

Comment: @MarkDenn: Very strange. It works for me. I know that the Unicode database gets updated regularly in Ruby, so this is version-dependent, but U+00A0 has been in Unicode since before Ruby even existed, so I doubt that is the problem. Note that your solution only works for this particular character. It will break in exactly the same way, whenever the *next* space character comes your way. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42410643/2988) where the asker had a Chinese space character.